# MySQL filter through a pivot table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm building a system where I need to be able to filter search results based on a many-to-many relationship.

I have a `users` table, a `bands` and a join table `band_user`

I need to select `users` where none of their favourite bands are touring or recording. I have a field on the band table `status` which I am filtering by.

```
SELECT `u`.*, COUNT(`b`.`id`) as `band_count` FROM `users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `band_users` `bu` on bu`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `bands` `b` on `bu`.`band_id` = `b`.`id`
WHERE `b`.`status` = "touring"
GROUP_BY `u`.`id`
HAVING `band_count` > 0
```

This query gives me a list of all the users who have at least 1 favourite band set as touring (Or recording if you change the status param).

What I am trying to do is select users who have all of their favourite bands having an 'idle' status.

I also need to give priority to users who have at least one band that is recording over touring, so if a user has a favourite band who is recording, and a favourite band who is touring, the users overall status is 'recording'

Comment: Perhaps `COUNT(b.id) as band_count` should be put before `from`. And for `LEFT JOIN bands b on bu.band_id = bu.id`, you may check the correction of the keys in both tables.

Comment: Oops, they're typos! Thanks for pointing them out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to only select the users whose favorite bands are **not** touring or recording.

```
SELECT `u`.*, COUNT(`b`.`id`) as `band_count` FROM `users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `band_users` `bu` on bu`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `bands` `b` on `bu`.`band_id` = `b`.`id`
WHERE `u`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `u`.`id`
FROM `users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `band_users` `bu` on bu`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `bands` `b` on `bu`.`band_id` = `b`.`id`
WHERE `b`.`status` = "touring" OR `b`.`status` = "recording")
GROUP_BY `u`.`id`
```

**Explanation**

The following query is used to select the user who has at least a favorite 
band on tour or recording.

```
SELECT `u`.`id`
FROM `users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `band_users` `bu` on bu`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `bands` `b` on `bu`.`band_id` = `b`.`id`
WHERE `b`.`status` = "touring" OR `b`.`status` = "recording"
```

I didn't fully get your meaning about the 'priority' you want to make for the recording bands, since all touring bands and recording bands have been removed in this query.

Comment: I eventually managed to accomplish everything I needed and came up with pretty much the same idea you did. The part about the priority was for a seperate query, which again follows a similar sub-query pattern, but the check for the `touring` is in the main query and the sub-query is used to filter the `recording` artists out.